# Application of a directed almost tree

Tags: graphs, terminology, binary-trees

Is there anything interesting to say about an "almost BST" with directed edges?
Is there a domain where this structure naturally arises? I'm imagining a tree like the one below, but it would of course be more interesting if the tree were deeper with just a few of these strange edges.

[image]

I found this article on circuit rank which uses the term "almost tree", but it talks about [circuits in undirected and directed graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_rank). What I'm describing is not a cycle.

Comment: Define "almost" and "few".

Comment: I meant "almost" and "few" in the spirit of "sparse matrix". You can't put a number to it but you know it when you see it.

Comment: That's not how definitions work.

Comment: A sparse matrix is a matrix in which most entries are zero. That definition has worked just fine for me for a few years. No one defines "most". I could put an arbitrary bound like "fewer than k 'crossing edges', where a 'crossing edge' is an edge from a node in one subtree to a node in another subtree". But deciding what value of k made this structure interesting wasn't the point of my question. Anyway, the answer seems clear: there isn't anything particularly interesting about this structure.

Comment: Can you ask a more specific question than "Is there anything interesting to say"?  What specifically do you want to know about those graphs?  This site works best when you are able to state a specific, narrowly focused, answerable question.  "What can you say about X?" usually isn't a good fit for this site format.

Comment: I've graduated  and I'm just working in industry so I don't have many people to day dream with about possibilities like this due to deadlines and family responsibilities... I should probably find a better outlet, but haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for are [directed acyclic graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAGs). If you want your DAG to have a unique "root", then you can ask for a DAG with a single *source*. DAGs are very useful in many branches of computer science.

Comment: True. I was just wondering if this particular class of DAG arises anywhere, but after two days research it seems that there isn't anything particularly special about this DAG. I guess we couldn't treat this as a binary search tree because the crossing edges between subtrees mean the set isn't totally ordered. Maybe there is something to say if the nodes belong to a partially ordered set.